# Using DATEDIFF to calculate a date key vs. joining on date lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm working with a database where I have to pull snapshots of records that are changing with time. The snapshots table only has start and end date ID columns, so the standard way of doing this is do join on a date lookup table.

Simplified example:

```
SELECT
            *
FROM
            records
INNER JOIN
            snapshots
        ON  records.RecordID = snapshots.RecordID
INNER JOIN
            dates
        ON  dates.id BETWEEN snapshots.StartDateID AND snapshots.EndDateID
        AND dates.date = '01-01-2018'
```

I've run in to situations where this seems to be very slow, though, presumably from having many snapshots to lookup over long ranges of dates.

I know that the ID for the date table is simply the number of days from `'1900-01-01'`. Knowing this I can calculate what would be the key explicitly.

E.g.:

```
SELECT
            *
FROM
            records
INNER JOIN
            snapshots
        ON  records.RecordID = snapshots.RecordID
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', '2018-01-01') BETWEEN snapshots.StartDateID AND snapshots.EndDateID
```

I have found that this does indeed work, and have come across situations where this seems to perform much faster.

Being a SQL novice, though, it's not clear to me if there is some pitfall I'm not seeing that should dissuade me from using the second method going forward.

Comment: Do you really need to `select *` if the snapshot table is just a reference to restrict the return?  You could probably gain some performance using a `where exists ()` here.

Comment: I'm not actually ever doing `select *` - just lazy typing for an example. The snapshot table isn't just a reference, though - there are a bunch of columns both in the snapshots table and in the reports table I'd actually be selecting.

Comment: Neither query is "wrong" then (aside from using the mm-dd-yyyy format, which i'm hoping is a typo too)... its likely an indexing issue.  You'll probably need to post an execution plan (using your actual query not `select *`)

Comment: Especially with dates using BETWEEN can cause you pull your hair out. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common